# Using OpenCV4Android, how to create an ROI (Region-Of-Interest or a submat) from a contour?

Tags: android, opencv, contour

Given an image `Mat`, and a contour (which is a `MatOfPoint`) in it, how can I create a ROI (Region Of Interest)/submat?

I can see three interesting methods on [docs of `Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Mat.html),

> **Mat submat(int rowStart, int rowEnd, int colStart, int colEnd)**
>        Extracts a rectangular submatrix.
>
> **Mat submat(Range rowRange, Range colRange)**
>        Extracts a rectangular submatrix.
>
> **Mat submat(Rect roi)**
>        Extracts a rectangular submatrix.

1. Is there a way to find out `rowStart`, `rowEnd`, `colStart` and
   `colEnd` from the contour?

or

2. Is there a way to get `rowRange` and `colRange` from the contour?

or

3. Can I make a `Rect` from the contour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Imgproc.boundingRect(MatOfPoint contour)`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect) method. This way you can use the third of the `submat()` methods you have listed:

```
Rect roiRect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour);
Mat roiSubmat = originalMat.submat(roiRect);
```

`roiSubmat` is your region of interest (stored in a Mat).